# ORA-01843: not a valid month error- have tried changing the date format but not working

Tags: oracle

This error comes up when I try to run the code on Oracle, but I'm not sure why. I think it is to do with the date format can anyone help?

```
INSERT INTO Subscription (Gym_ID, Member_ID, Current_or_Old_Susbcription, Susbcription_StartDate, Subscription_EndDate, Susbcription_Cost)

VALUES (1, 2, 'Current', '01/01/2016', '31/12/2016', '480');
```

Comment: Then use the default date format: `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: Well then try `2016-12-31`

Comment: `VALUES (1, 2, 'Current', '01/01/2016', '31/12/2016', '480');` should be 
`VALUES (1, 2, 'Current', '01/01/2016', '12/31/2016', '480');` because the ISO Standard doesn't support `dd-mm-yyyy` format

Answer (score 2):

Use the `date` keyword and ISO standard formats:

```
INSERT INTO Subscription (Gym_ID, Member_ID, Current_or_Old_Subscription, Subscription_StartDate, Subscription_EndDate, Subscription_Cost)
    VALUES (1, 2, 'Current', DATE '2016-01-01', DATE '2016-12-01', '480');
```

This isolates you from any special settings you might have on your server.

Answer (score 2):

'01/01/2016' and '31/12/2016' are strings not dates. So the DBMS has to convert. You don't use a conversion function (which would be `to_date`), so the DBMS must use default settings. It may be it thinks 31 and not 12 is the month. Use date literals instead:

```
INSERT INTO Subscription (Gym_ID, Member_ID, Current_or_Old_Subscription,
                          Subscription_StartDate, Subscription_EndDate, Subscription_Cost)
VALUES (1, 2, 'Current', date'2016-01-01', date'2016-12-31', '480');
```